# How to be confident that a websocket is secured

Tags: node.js, websocket

This may sound like an absurd question and probably it is.
Right now I use [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node) but may switch to [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) soon.
So answers for both implementations are welcome.

I open a listener on port 8080 and wait for a connection request. Immediately after accepting the request I want to be confident that the connection is secured (as in: use `wss://` and reject simple `ws://`).

The trivial code taken from the documentation is:

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {

  // TODO: produce this single bit
  SSL_IS_ACTIVE = ?;

  if (!SSL_IS_ACTIVE) {
    request.reject(); // ws protocol used, I want wss!
    return;
  }

  // ... proceed to process the request (authentication and so on)
}
```

As simple as this may sound I've not found any documentation about this.

Do I have to stick to the SSL port (443) or can I still choose any port, e.G. using:

```
wss://localhost:8080/test
```

Is there a way to test the protocol and does it suffice, e.G. something along the lines:

```
request.protocol === "wss"
-or-
request.uri.indexOf("wss://") === 0
```

It looks like I'm missing something because it's not possible I'm the only one with this problem :D

Any help is appreciated for both implementations (*WebSocket-Node* and *ws*)!

Comment: can `verifyClient` help?
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L33, firefox 8 + looks like it enforces that if your site is ssl only secure websocket can be used.  I haven't really used websockets but feel like there should be a way to expliclity bind your server to wss only

Comment: I'll look into this, too. Considering that I use nw.js (thus, a specific version of CEF) I think there'll be an equivalent behavior to that of Firefox 8+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like a straightforward way to ensure that no unsecure requests are being made is to not even support unsecured requests when constructing your server.  It looks like `WebSocket.Node` supports Secure servers.  I'd imagine that `ws` should too.  I think there should be a way to only bind to `wss` for both projects.

from `WebSocket.Node` it looks like you can create TLS server using:

> TLS supported for server connections (use https.createServer instead
>   of http.createServer)

from the docs: https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node

Comment: That line totally slipped under my radar! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

> The WebSocket protocol specification defines two new URI schemes, ws: and wss:, for unencrypted and encrypted connections respectively. Apart from the scheme name and fragment (# is not supported), the rest of the URI components are defined to use [URI generic syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax).

As such, you can specify ports in websocket urls the same way as you would for normal web urls.

Comment: Thank you! I had to accept the other answer because it points to an actual implementation detail. Your answer is still relevant but I can only accept one...